# Eclipse Windowbuilder Unknown GUI toolkit

Tags: java, eclipse, windowbuilder

I'm trying to use Windowbuilder on Eclipse but it always pops up error "Unknown GUI toolkit". 
[image]
[image]

The mainFrame.java is created by the drop down menu below:
[image]

I install Windowbuilder from Eclipse MarketPlace.

Looks like everything is installed properly, including SWT Designer.
[image]

Here is all my environment: 
computer: macbook pro intel i5 
Eclipse: 2023-03 (4.27.0) 
Java JDK: 17.0.6

I tried un/install Windowbuilder several times but every time end up having the same problem, and I even reinstall java JDK and Eclipse.

Comment: Which GUI toolkit do you use, Swing or SWT? Please show `mainFrame.java` and tell how you have created it.

Comment: I'm using Swing and I update my mainFrame.java above. But actually I just tried SWT it comes to the same result.

Comment: I create Swing Application Window by clicking the shortcut button on Eclipse, and it automatically creates a mainFrame.java file for me under src folder of my java project, which looks good.

Comment: You must first fix the errors to be able to use WindowBuilder. If you have a `module-info.java` file, delete it (if needed you can recreate it later via right-click on project and _Configure_) or [in `module-info.java` add the required `requires ...;` statement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Platform_Module_System#Properties_of_modules). `mainFrame.java` does not look like created by WindowBuilder, right?

Comment: It works after I delete module-info.java, why are those files related? I update how I create mainFrame.java above.

Comment: So, does it work now? Follow the link in my previous comment to learn about the `module-info.java` file.